# Python runs functions that are elements of a declared dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

As soon as i define this dictionary:

```
case_dict={
    "run" : runn(),
    "name" : namee(),
    "help" : helpp(),
    "quit": quitt(),
}
```

python runs all these functions successively. How do i avoid these functions from running in the console when i just want to define the dict  ?

PS: all these functions are defined earlier in the code.

Comment: When do you plan to execute them ? What exactly do you expact to happen?

Comment: `runn` is the name of a function object and `runn()` is a call to it.

Comment: I plan to execute them when i call them from the dict later on in the program

Answer (score 3):

You assigned the value of each key to the return value of the function, not the function itself.
Through the brackets at the end the functions get executed the moment you create the dict.

to avoid this, write `runn` instead of `runn()`

so you would end up with

```
case_dict={
    "run" : runn,
    "name" : namee,
    "help" : helpp,
    "quit": quitt,
}
```

Now, if you would like to call one of these functions you would do it like so:

```
case_dict["run"](parameter_1, parameter_2 ... )
```

Comment: yes, but when i call an element of the dict like: case_dict["run"] it doesn't run the function, it returns the runn function object.
I want each function defined as an element of the dict to run when i call it from the dict.

Comment: yes, in order to call the function you always have to use brackets. so you would have to write `case_dict["run"]()`

Comment: Ohh ok, now i get it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @bendo97 that isn't what "calling" means